# Primary text color for differents attributes

Tags: android, xml, styles

i have my primary text color define like this :

```
<color name="primaryTextColor">#ff82ff26</color>
```

and also in my style.xml :

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/AccentColor</item>

        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

    </style>


</resources>
```

the problem is that the color is modified everywhere and also into my listview but i want the text to my listview to be a different color is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to inflate the listview, can make a simple layout with one textview then inflate it, and change the color with `android:textColor="@color/someColor"`

Answer (score 0):

In your android resource `style.xml` file add this `<item name="textColorPrimary">#10a2fc</item>` to change your primary text color. Change the hex value `#10a2fc` or use color picker for change the color as you need.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        //change this hex code or use color picker for change your primary text color 
        <item name="textColorPrimary">#10a2fc</item>


    </style>

</resources>
```

Let me know if your problem is solved.